# Physical difference of waves produced by a deep and a treble

Tags: acoustics

I tried to find what the difference is on the pressure wave caused by a bass speaker and a wave produced by a treble speaker.

Off course the frequency is lower on the bass wave, but is that all? Why does the waves from the bass speaker appear to have a much stronger and bigger sound intensity than the treble speaker?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do the bass and treble speakers you're comparing have the same power consumption average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the bass frequency is lower, its wavelength is longer, because the speed of sound is roughly constant, so the sound wave travels further in one full cycle.

But the efficiency of the speaker depends on the ratio of its diameter to the wavelength. So a bass speaker must be bigger than a treble speaker.

Comment: ... and therefore ... ?

Comment: @docscience, and therefore woofers are bigger than tweeters.

Comment: yes true. But you are not relating that to the original question which I  believe has to do with the relative intensity or power from each device. Sound systems split, filter frequency bands. But what if you ran the same broad band signal into each speaker? What would the relative *intensity* or power of the sound waves be in that case?

Comment: @docscience, I'm sure someone with more acoustics background than me can write a better answer. I only answered because the question had been sitting for a (short) while without getting a response.

Comment: Thank you @ThePhoton! It made it a lot more clear, and even pointed to where i myself could do some more research. Thanks!